# At the end of The Crippled God, where does the Otataral Dragon end up?

Tags: malazan

At the end of the 10th book, The Crippled God, we see the capture/release of a few very important characters.

> All the Eleint i.e. the dragons come together to fight the Otataral Dragon. They do this since it's aspect is that of Otataral, which negates magic. All the other Eleint are aspected to some type of magic or warren. They might've killed the Otataral dragon, which according to Kilmandaros, an Elder God, wouldn't bode well for the world. Something to do with maintaining the balance, yin and yang.

But the Bonehunters, along with some other players come together to stop this from happening.

> I recall something about the Otataral Dragon being *chained* maybe? in a cavern under the Adjunct's sword.

Where exactly does the Otataral Dragon a.k.a Korabas end up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## She was (re)chained in a barrow beneath the Otataral sword carried by Adjunct Tavore.

At the end of *The Crippled God*, Korabas was drawn to the Glass Desert by Adjunct Tavore's Otataral sword.  Once she was there, Heboric Light-Touch with some assistance from The Crippled God chained Korabas once again in a barrow underneath the sword. 
The Crippled God's assistance amounted to giving up his own chains for Heboric to use in chaining Korabas.

According to the [Malazan wiki](http://malazan.wikia.com/wiki/Heboric_Light_Touch), Korabas was chained to help save her from T'iam, but I can't honestly recall where this came up or why she needed to be "saved" from T'iam.

Comment: If anyone else remembers more accurately T'iam's involvement, please say so.  This series is so dense and expansive it's difficult to try and remember how all the pieces fit together so I'm grateful for the help.

Comment: I don't think it meant saving her from Tiam personally. Probably it meant, with Korabas being chained, there needn't be a convergence of the Eleint. No convergence, no Tiam. Is that what they meant?

Comment: T'iam is dead (it's how Soletaken were created initially, although the process is still vague), so I agree it probably isn't a direct threat.  I think you're probably on the right path in terms of there being a convergence of Eleint (who are all said to be children of T'iam) that all were trying to kill her.

Comment: I thought a convergence of Eleint resurrected..raised up..whatever. I thought Tiam could be brought back again?